# Dominated convergence 2.0?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

During my research, I came across the following question.

Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence in $C^2([0,1])$ converging pointwise to $g \in L^1([0,1])$. Assume that:

$\forall n\in\mathbb N, f_n''<h$, where $h$ is locally integrable on $]0,1[$.

Is it true that $\lim \int_0^1 f_n=\int_0^1 g$ ?

Comment: Did you not mean $|f_n''|<h$?

Comment: No, without absolute value

Comment: Do you mind to share what you have tried? +1 for the question.. I would really love to see what you have tried..

Comment: @GHfromMO I am not sure how clasical analysis and odes tag is relevant here...  Can you tell me how that is relevant here?

Comment: I assume that "converging pointwise to a function in $L^1$" means pointwise convergence almost everywhere?

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik :  the convergence 's localy uniforme, but it's not suffised to conclued

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta I think it is point wise convergence.. not almost everywhere...

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta : yes every where in [0,1]

Comment: I wanted to see more of what you have tried than that... Do not take it otherwise.. just curious..

Comment: Letting $h$ be only locally integrable seems like not enough to rule out garden-variety counterexamples, such as smoothed-out triangles of base $1/n$ and height $n$ centered at $x=1/n$. $\sup f_n''$ will blow up like $n^3$, but you can still bound $f_n''$ by an $h(x)$ proportional to $1/x^3$ which is *locally* integrable on $(0,1)$ but obviously not integrable.

Comment: @user37208 : possible, I'm waiting to see this counter-example with justification

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Every question should have a high-level tag like ca, nt, etc. (the available tags are the same as in the arXiv). For this question, the best high-level tag is ca. It is a question belonging to analysis.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but don't we get a simple counterexample by defining $f_n(x) := - a_n/(x + 1/n)$ where $a_n > 0$ is chosen such that each $f_n$ has integral $-1$? (Note that $a_n \to 0$.) Or do you consider it a problem that $g(0) = \infty$ in this example?

Comment: $\forall x\in [0,1], f_n(x)$ converged to $g(x) \in \mathbb R$

Comment: @Dattier: I see. This makes the question much more involved, of course :-). +1

Comment: @Dattier: Well, given the counterexample below, I should probably be a bit more careful with my usage of the phrase "of course"... ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Counterexample.** Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ denote your favourite test function with support in $(0,1)$ and with integral $1$. We define $f_n(x) := n f(nx)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $x \in [0,1]$.

Then $f_n(x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and $\int_0^1 f_n = 1$ for all $n$. If we define $M := \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \lvert f''(x) \rvert$, then $\lvert f_n''(x)\rvert \le n^3 M$ for each $x \in [0,1]$ and each index $n$. Since $f_n$ is supported on $(0,1/n)$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
  f_n''(x) \le \lvert f_n''(x) \rvert < M/x^3
\end{align*}
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $x \in (0,1)$.

**Remark.** I'd say this counterexample can be considered as an abstract version of the construction skechted by user37208 in the comments.

Comment: $f_n(0)=n\times f(0) $ and $f(0)>0$ so $\lim f_n(0)=+\infty$, no ?

Comment: @Dattier: We have $f(0) = 0$ since $f$ is supported in the open interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: what about the case where $h \in L^1([0,1])$ : @Jochen Glueck

Comment: @Dattier: I'm not sure about this case, unfortunately. Under the stronger assumptions that $\lvert f_n''\rvert \le h$ for $h \in L^1$ and that $(f_n'(0))$ be bounded, we can apply the dominated convergence theorem. If, however, only $f_n'' \le h$ for $h \in L^1$ (or if nothing is assumed on $(f_n'(0))$), then I don't know what happens. Maybe this would be appropriate for a new question?

Comment: here, the new question : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308686/dominated-convergence-2-1